# Restrict or limit read_very_eager() in python

Tags: python, telnetlib

I am executing a few commands on a remote machine which runs linux over a telnet session using telnet lib. When I give the following :

```
tn.write("<binary_name>")
time.sleep(10)
tn.write("cat <path_of_output_file>")
rd_buf=tn.read_very_eager()
print(rd_buf)
```

it gives the output of the binary and the output of `cat` command. While I only want the output of the `cat` command. I have only worked with `read_very_eager` and `read_until`. How do I restrict my buffer variable to hold only the contents of the `cat` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of playing around with `read_until()` and `read_very_eager()`, I finally solved this. All I had to do was this :

```
tn.write("<binary_name>")
time.sleep(10)
junk=tn.read_very_eager()
tn.write("cat <path_of_output_file>")
rd_buf=tn.read_very_eager()
print(rd_buf)
```

With the addition of 1 line (`junk=tn.read_very_eager()`), I am able to achieve what I wanted. Quoting the python official documentation :

> Telnet.read_very_eager()
>
> > Read everything that can be without blocking in I/O (eager).

I took a cue from this and made the script forcefully halt the "reading". And begin reading all over again, which served the purpose.